What determines the resistance with which MOSFETs fail short?
In the case of electrical or thermal overload, MOSFETs usually fail short with a relatively low resistance in the range of ohms or tens of ohms. This answer on "Do MOSFETs usually burn open or closed?" gives a reason why this happens.
For a FMEA it might also be helpful to understand with what resistance a MOSFET can and cannot fail. I was unable to find information on that. Can anybody fill this gap?
My thinking is that more heat probably means lower resistance failure? Too much heat will end up blowing up the FET?
The resistance might depend on the voltage and current limit of the source that drives power into the failed MOSFET.
Say we have a 12V 20A power supply and a failed MOSFET causing a short on the output of that supply. Can we say something about the possible resistance range that the MOSFET can fail to? Will we run into the 20A current limit of the supply in any case?

It will take a lot of research and paperwork to prove tight assertions about the possible range of resistances.
Conservatively, assume whatever resistance gives you the worst outcomes for any fault scenario you are considering. It may mean a different resistance for each scenario - that's normal. Assume an antagonistic mosfet :)

Will we run into the 20A current limit of the supply in any case?

Surely the broken MOSFET dissipating 240 W of heat in a small volume is worth thinking about first? And if that MOSFET subsequently fails open because it has evaporated its guts, the supply won't be loaded anymore :)

So you are suggesting following the conservative approach and first assuming everything is possible and then checking if the "solution" is plausible? So another boundary condition might be at what power the MOSFET package actually blows up. I would still be interested in getting more insight into the failure process, like a resistance over time graph after a failure with more information what actually happens. But maybe it cannot be generalized.

During these types of analyses, more conservative is often better than less conservative. You should probably also try to verify some of your failure modes (and detection/mitigation strategies) by doing fault injection testing

The lower limit is probably similar or even less than Rds(on). The resistance of the bonding wires will remain, until it doesn't.
Think of it as a couple fuses (bonding wires) in series with a heat-sensitive semiconductor that can melt and permanently turn into a fairly good conductor.
There are also failures caused by excessive gate voltage, but I don't think you're talking about that.

So given the 12V 20A supply example, the MOSFET bond wires will probably not blow up since the current is too low. But can you make any statement about the resistance it could end up with? 12V/20A = 0.6 Ohm would be the maximum power. But that resistance cannot be permanently sustained because 240W will cause too high of a temperature. Will it be less or more?

If it's Rds(on) that resistance could be < 0.001Ω, so I don't think you can make any general statements until you specify a particular MOSFET, and even then..  I also think it's possible to have failures that are much higher resistance than if you outright melt the die, perhaps by exceeding SOA and causing hot spots.

Can definitely have point failures (most often I would say, from gate breakdown, or avalanche breakdown in the case of BJTs), where the device seems to have a modest resistance between pins (D-S, or G-S and G-D), but overall it still transists -- it just never completely turns off, among other problems. Mind, of the possible semiconductor failure modes and methods, I've triggered/observed only a few of them over my career; consider this a possibility, or anecdote, not data.

As Tim says- minor damage (eg. from radiation) can cause what looks like increased leakage, and I would expect thermal damage would be similar. There is a huge space of possible ways to damage a part and most of us have not gone out of our way to contribute to knowledge in the field.
